# Can a nested Div ignore the parent Div width?

Tags: css, html

Basically I have a nested `<div>` as a footer and the parent div is centered 1000px wide.
I was wondering if it was possible to extend the width of footer div so that it goes out of the parent to fit the browsers width but still keeps its place in the parent?

[image]

Comment: There are probably a few ways to sort of achieve this but why not just put the footer outside the parent?

Comment: I'm new to using Divs and when I put the footer outside of the parent, it ends up being in the middle of my page. I put it in the parent div so that it ends up at the bottom of everything else

Comment: Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kKScJ/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution assumes that `.parent` element has stretched height. even if it is not the case, then it seems you want the `.footer` element stick to the bottom of the page. If it is so, then using `position:absolute` you can bring the child block out of the parent block and then pin it to bottom using `bottom: 0px` and then to stretch its width use `left:0px` and `right: 0px`.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kKScJ/)

**UPDATED**:

Use this Doctype declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Also, in `.footer` element mention `top:auto` css property. Something like this:

```
.footer{
    padding: 0px 15px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #1A1A1A;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: auto;  /* added (IE FIX) */
}
```

Comment: This wont work when your body content goes beyond the browser window (i.e. the browser has a scroll bar show. Try [this changed jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/purnil/kKScJ/1/). Problem happens when you scroll down.

Comment: @PurnilSoni In that case, use `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute`.

Comment: Have modified your fiddle example. Please visit [this changed jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/purnil/kKScJ/1/)

Comment: @PurnilSoni no need of `position: fixed` also. just remove `bottom: 0px` which is used for pinning the `.footer` element to bottom. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kKScJ/2/).

Comment: This works perfect but the footer isn't at the bottom on IE :(

Comment: @Mr_Green just added it into my original post. Might be a little weird to make out but you can see where the dark grey line (the footer) goes across the middle of the page

Comment: @Adsy is this happening when you scroll down? or from first itself the footer is visible like that? and also what is the version of IE?

Comment: this is a view from the bottom of the page. but in IE the footer isn't even at the bottom of the page when you first open the page, not as if "bottom: 0px" had been used.

Comment: @Adsy Did you add `DOCTYPE` declaration on above of your HTML code?

Comment: The doc type I am using is `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: @Adsy Try using "_Strict Doctype_". before that try giving `top: auto`. and please tell me what is the version of IE?

Comment: What is a Strict Doctype? and if you mean add "top: auto" to my footer, i tried that and it does nothing. Sorry for my lack of understanding! oh and i'm using IE10

Comment: AHHH! never mind, I got it! It's because The contact form I am using is an iframe and IE is acting like it's not there and putting the footer before it. I just put the iframe in a div and it's all fine now :) I appreciate all of your help anyway @Mr_Green!

Answer (score 2):

Something that would work for you:

```
.parent{
    width: 300px; /* your parent width */
}
.footer{
    height: 50px; /* your footer height */
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kKScJ/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You could set the footer position to relative and set the left property to -100px and width to 1200px for example.

Better still don't have it in the parent div, have it as it's own div with it's own values set.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

html

```
<div id="parent" class="wrap"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

css

```
.wrap{width: 1000px;}
#footer{width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS.

```
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css this will definitely work as you want

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.parent{
    width: 400px;/*put your width here*/
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;    
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.footer{
    padding: 15px 0px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #000;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width:100%
}
```

Comment: `love-trivedi` this is what @Mr_Green has provided in his solution. Hope you are not copy pasting from other's work.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to bypass the parent element, you could look into `display:contents`

https://css-tricks.com/get-ready-for-display-contents/

It really is a game changer if you need a div to wrap elements for some logic reason, but want the styling of all seperate elements.

Example without:

```css
.main {
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="title">
    <h2>Foo</h2>&nbsp;
    <span>Bar</span>
  </div>

  <button>shamefull_button</button>

</div>
```

Example with:

```css
.main {
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.title {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="title">
    <h2>Foo</h2>&nbsp;
    <span>Bar</span>
  </div>

  <button>shameless_button</button>

</div>
```